# C# windows service sometimes hangs on Executing sql update

Tags: c#

I am doing a simple update, of a bit in a table using the code below.  However, sometimes the program hangs on myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();  and I don't know why.  If Sql server is down, it will drop into the catch statement as expected but sometimes, for seemingly no reason, it will just hang on the execution statement.  Any Ideas.... Some of my code is below.

Thanks

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand);
            connection = new SqlConnection(constr);
            myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

```
        myCommand.Connection = connection;

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("There was an inserting information from the Sql server<br>" +
                "The server error was: <br>" + ex.Message + "<br>");  

        }
        finally
        {
            this.CloseConnection();
        }
```

Comment: If it's not the connection timing out (i.e. server being down) then it's more than likely going to be to do with the SQL you're executing. Can you post your SQL statement being run?

Comment: UPDATE ServiceWatchDog
SET watchCount = @watchCount
WHERE id= '1'

I am basically setting a bit to 1... very simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A timeout is probably the cause. Though there's not enough info in your post to be certain. Try setting the [command execution timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx).

Comment: I don't have a timeout set... I assumed there is a default timeout.  Is this not the case?

Comment: Default is 30. Code hanging with ExecuteNonQuery() is either a though query or a deadlock. Are there multiple processes updating the data?

Comment: There are two services that access this bit, one writes it to 0 and the other writes it to 1.... collision possible?  How would I stop that from happening?

Comment: You could try changing the transaction isolation level or use a mutex to prevent the two processes from writing at the same time.

Comment: That might be the solutions... let me give that a shot.

Comment: I think your suggestion is the key... only time will tell.  I also added some error handling to the stored procedure to try and error more gracefully. Thanks!